# Possessive or objective?

Tags: grammar

I wondered about this grammar point, i.e. the possessive and the objective functionalities of `'s`.

For example, you have "JFK's murder" to mean "the murder of JFK" (which is objective).

On the other hand, Mary's book is possessive.

So, does this mean `'s` has both functionalities?

Comment: It does indeed have both functionalities, and it can also be subjective: "Robert's gift of $1000". You can only know which is in play by context.

Comment: In this case it means Robert gave someone a gift of that amount right?

Comment: Think of possessive pronouns/determiners, it will help. *Your shoe* is something you own; *your friend* isn't. (Not just in English, I might add, in pretty much all languages.) Likewise, *'s* is not really about possession at all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't read too much into the designation ***possessive*** apostrophe. It might make it easier if you think of the usage as...

> ***X's Y*** = *the Y **associated with** X*, rather than *the Y **belonging to** X*.